# Importing 100MB XML file into iOS Core Data Model

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, core-data, ipad

In my app I need to import a 100MB xml file into a Core Data Model.

So far, I've imported a 100KB xml file and everything works fine. However, not sure how long it takes to import a 100MB xml. I will run it tonite, in the while.. do you think this approach is good ?

thanks

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Delete all documents
    NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
    for (id basket in result)
        [context deleteObject:basket];



    //Insert documents
    TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLFile:@"categ_small.xml"] retain];
    TBXMLElement * root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
    TBXMLElement * doc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"doc" parentElement:root];

    do {
        TBXMLElement * idDoc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"id" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * titleDoc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * descriptionDoc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"description" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * time = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"time" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * tags = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"tags" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * geo = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"geo" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * event = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"event" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * user = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"user" parentElement:doc];
        TBXMLElement * categ = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"categ" parentElement:doc];

        NSManagedObject *newDocument = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:idDoc] forKey:@"idDoc"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:titleDoc] forKey:@"titleDoc"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:descriptionDoc] forKey:@"descriptionDoc"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:time] forKey:@"time"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:tags] forKey:@"tags"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:geo] forKey:@"geo"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:event] forKey:@"event"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:user] forKey:@"user"];
        [newDocument setValue:[TBXML textForElement:categ] forKey:@"categ"];

    } while ((doc = doc->nextSibling));
```

**UPDATE**
This is a one-time operation which runs in the Simulator only, and it won't be deployed with the final application.

Comment: No, its pretty much everything but not good.

Comment: @JustSid ok, thanks! Do you mind to share why ?

Comment: If it's only going to be run on the simulator, why not just try it?

Comment: @paulbailey Because it takes a while. Anyway I've tried and after a while I get a bad memory access error (while with a small file it perfectly works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do the following steps:

- Write a converter XML->SQLite with ruby or php, or if you are not a friend of scripting languages then have a look at SQLite Manager it's a Firefox Plugin to manage SQLite database and it's capable of importing XML.
- Prepopulate core-data for shipping following this tutorial: [How To Preload/Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data)

Answer (score 3):

Putting a document that size in resident memory is a quick way to get your app killed by the system.

To import an XML document that large on a system with limited resources you'll want streamed parsing, which will keep the resident memory footprint small. There are plenty of options here. Apple's NSXMLParser will do the trick, although it's not as fast as some of the alternatives. (A good overview of those alternatives is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).)

For the implementation, I suggest parsing in an `NSOperation` subclass, periodically notifying the main thread with progress updates. This will prevent the UI from blocking as you parse arbitrarily large documents.

Using `NSEntityDescription` the way you are will create individual autoreleased objects for every doc sibling in the XML file, which is another quick way to run short of memory. Take a look at Apple's [Efficiently Importing Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) documentation for the correct way to do this.

Comment: thanks. (1) I've actually picked TBXML parser because it is the fastest according to the link you passed me (I've already read it).  (2) For "streamed parsing", you mean to parse and directly store the data into the core model ? (3) I forgot to mention that the parsing obviously happens only once, and I won't use xml file anymore.

Comment: So, if you mean I should use a SAX parser and not a DOM parser, I guess TBXML (DOM parser) is not a good option, for low memory devices. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: It's fastest, but it uses a DOM, so the entire thing is in resident memory. That's fine for smaller documents you'll be referring to frequently, but it's terrible for working with very large documents, especially on systems with limited resources. If you just need to do the import once and ship a prepopulated DB, Nick's suggestion is the one to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off process used to build an CoreData or SQLite database to distribute with you app, It will likely work, but only on the simulator. However, if you need to perform this on the device, you'll need to switch to a streaming parser.

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention is one-off process only for simulator indeed. It is surely not the most efficient way, but do you think I can just run this code tonite ? Or there is some optimization I can do ?

Comment: It should work. The simulator isn't an emulator, so it should have access to memory on your Mac, rather than the limited memory on any particular iOS device.

Comment: Instead I got a bad memory access only if the file is large, wierd. With the small file everything is fine. I will inspect the file...